# Tweets over a specific time span (TwitteR)

Tags: r, twitter

Is there any way to fetch tweets over a specific time span (say, between December and January) with twitteR rather than simply the past N tweets (as in with tweets <- UserTimeline(user, n = 1000) ?

Or is that not possible using the TwitteR library? (meaning that you have to use something like Excel to subset a large number of tweets by date).

Comment: It seems that the twitter API does not support time spans when querying user time lines: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the package you're using, the `searchTwitter` function takes the arguments `since` and `until`, defined in the [documentation](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twitteR/twitteR.pdf) as follows:

> **since**  If not NULL, restricts tweets to those since the given date.
>   Date is to be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD
>
> **until**  If not NULL, restricts tweets to those up until the given date.
>   Date is to be formatted as YYYY-MM-DD

Is that what you're after? Or if you want to stick with the `userTimeline` function, you can subset the date range you want by operating on the `created` field of the  `status` object that you get (so no need to use Excel).

**EDIT** Here's how you might subset on the `created` field if you're using `userTimeline`:

```
library(twitteR)
# get last 100 tweets from the NSF
tweets <- userTimeline('NSF', 100)
# inspect structure of first item in the status object (ie. list of results)
str(tweets[1])
List of 1
 $ :Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 10 fields
  ..$ text        : chr "From the field: Avoiding a Cartography Catastrophe:  Study recommends new tools to improve global mapping of inf... http://t.co"| __truncated__
  ..$ favorited   : logi FALSE
  ..$ replyToSN   : chr(0) 
  ..$ created     : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2013-02-05 01:43:45"
  ..$ truncated   : logi FALSE
  ..$ replyToSID  : chr(0) 
  ..$ id          : chr "298607815617036288"
  ..$ replyToUID  : chr(0) 
  ..$ statusSource: chr "<a href=\"http://twitterfeed.com\" rel=\"nofollow\">twitterfeed</a>"
  ..$ screenName  : chr "NSF"
  ..and 34 methods, of which 23 are possibly relevant:
  ..  getCreated, getFavorited, getId, getReplyToSID, getReplyToSN,
  ..  getReplyToUID, getScreenName, getStatusSource, getText,
  ..  getTruncated, initialize, setCreated, setFavorited, setId,
  ..  setReplyToSID, setReplyToSN, setReplyToUID, setScreenName,
      ..  setStatusSource, setText, setTruncated, toDataFrame, usingMethods


# convert status object to data frame for easier manipulation
tweetsdf <- twListToDF(tweets)


 # subset by `created` field, eg get all tweets between 2 Feb and 5 Feb  
    subset(tweetsdf, created >= as.POSIXct('2013-02-02 00:00:00') & created <= as.POSIXct('2013-02-05 00:00:00'))
```

And here's the dataframe that results from that subset operation:

```
text
1   From the field: Avoiding a Cartography Catastrophe:  Study recommends new tools to improve global mapping of inf... http://t.co/F6IJ05Sb
2                  Video: Research Vessel Sikuliaq launched... and now being prepared for her first Arctic run in 2014, http://t.co/D7GlRnlm
3                                                                                        Who's watching the power grid? http://t.co/oYsgBl63
4 Ice Melt &amp; the Ice Age... research story on #AAAS #Science Update Daily, featured show @Science360 Radio, http://t.co/XRXSdYL1 #Arctic
5                                                                                             Taking LIGO to the people http://t.co/R2KHNQTB
6                            Pubs: NSF Current - January-February 2013: Available Formats: JSP: http://t.co/2NhEEj6Q... http://t.co/ZSVABpXm
7   Upcoming Due Dates: Interdisciplinary Research in Hazards and Disasters (Hazards SEES): Full Proposal Deadline D... http://t.co/IG3naAFs
8                                                     When children learn to walk, their language improves dramatically http://t.co/FGYXSKu2
  favorited replyToSN             created truncated replyToSID
1     FALSE        NA 2013-02-05 01:43:45     FALSE         NA
2     FALSE        NA 2013-02-04 19:30:40     FALSE         NA
3     FALSE        NA 2013-02-04 18:01:33     FALSE         NA
4     FALSE        NA 2013-02-04 13:55:46     FALSE         NA
5     FALSE        NA 2013-02-04 13:01:51     FALSE         NA
6     FALSE        NA 2013-02-02 17:19:30     FALSE         NA
7     FALSE        NA 2013-02-02 14:25:15     FALSE         NA
8     FALSE        NA 2013-02-02 14:02:11     FALSE         NA
                  id replyToUID
1 298607815617036288         NA
2 298513923307630592         NA
3 298491499958644736         NA
4 298429645580288000         NA
5 298416076012785666         NA
6 297756138433290240         NA
7 297712287521841156         NA
8 297706485608218624         NA
                                                     statusSource
1 <a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a>
2 <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
3 <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
4 <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
5 <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
6 <a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a>
7 <a href="http://twitterfeed.com" rel="nofollow">twitterfeed</a>
8 <a href="http://www.hootsuite.com" rel="nofollow">HootSuite</a>
  screenName
1        NSF
2        NSF
3        NSF
4        NSF
5        NSF
6        NSF
7        NSF
8        NSF
```

Comment: I think he is using the ```userTimeline``` function but ```searchTwitter``` may be able to stand in for it if it can be restricted to the tweets of a single user.

Comment: Yes, I see, seems that either they will have to subset `user` (if using `searchTwitter`) or `created` (if using `userTimeline`) to get tweets for a specific user during a specific date range. Looks like there isn't a one-liner for that purpose...

Comment: How do I go about accessing the created field of the status object? If my object is tweets <- userTimeline(user, 100), would I have something like subset(tweets, tweets@created == 2012-11-12, tweets@created == 2012-12-12) ?

Comment: Yes, that's almost right, see the example I've added to my answer. Does that do what you want? Have a look here for more on working with dates: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/help-subsetting-data-based-on-date-AND-time-tp3799933p3800212.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best way, as far as I can see, is https://rdrr.io/cran/rtweet/man/search_fullarchive.html -
at least if you have an academic twitter account. With something like
tweets <- search_fullarchive(
"#blabla",
n = 1000,
fromDate = YYYYMMDDHHMM,
toDate = 202203150000,
env_name = "to be declared on twitter (environment) for
your account"
)
you can search whatever you want .. without being limited to single users.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).